# Loop for making and outputting multiple linear regessions

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, statsmodels

I have multiple models I want to build. Im looking for a way to loop through my list to make and print out summary for each model.

```
x = data[["Prod Order Quantity", "Print Type Complexity " ]]
y1 = data["Per Unit Downtime and setup"]
y2 = data["Per Unit Runtime"]
y3 = data["Setup and downtime"]
y4 = data["Total Runtime"]
y5 = data["Total Variable Cost over Runtime"] 

#add constant list
Xc = sm.add_constant(x)
#make linear regression for 1 outcome variable at a time
model = sm.OLS(y1, Xc)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())

#loop to do it for each variable in my list 
all_outcomes = [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]
def all_models(variable_list): 
    for v in all_outcomes:
        model = sm.OLS[v,Xc]
        results = model.fit
        print(results.summary())

all_models(all_outcomes)
```

Error

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1):

You need `sm.OLS(v,Xc)` and ideally use the variable defined. Something like below will work, I first set up an example data like yours:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(100,7)))
data.columns = ["Prod Order Quantity", "Print Type Complexity","Per Unit Downtime and setup","Per Unit Runtime","Setup and downtime","Total Runtime","Total Variable Cost over Runtime"]
```

Define a function, and in this case it returns a list of the results:

```
def all_models(variable_list,df):
    #store results
    allresults = [] 
    
    for v in variable_list:
        Xc = sm.add_constant(df[["Prod Order Quantity", "Print Type Complexity"]])
        model = sm.OLS(df[v],Xc)
        results = model.fit()
        print(results.summary())
        allresults.append(results)

    return allresults
```

Run it:

```
all_outcomes = ["Per Unit Downtime and setup","Per Unit Runtime","Setup and downtime","Total Runtime","Total Variable Cost over Runtime"]

res = all_models(all_outcomes,data)
```